# Date difference won't work, datetime object

Tags: php, datetime

I am trying to get the difference between 2 dates in, years, months, days, hours and weeks.

But when I do it the object crash the page.

`$row['timedate']` is a DateTime column from the database

```
$content_date = $row['timedate'];
$content_date = (new DateTime($content_date))->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$now_date = (new DateTime('now'))->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$since_start = $content_date->diff($now_date);

echo $since_start->days . ' days total<br>';
echo $since_start->y . ' years<br>';
echo $since_start->m . ' months<br>';
echo $since_start->d . ' days<br>';
echo $since_start->h . ' hours<br>';
echo $since_start->i . ' minutes<br>';
echo $since_start->s . ' seconds<br>';
```

If i echo `$content_date` its equal to 2019-02-25 01:44:51

If i echo `$now_date` its equal to 2019-02-25 02:29:32

Can someone tell me why this does not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not be formatting `$content_date` and `$now_date` as strings if you want to use the `DateTime::diff` method. Instead, leave them as `DateTime` objects:

```
$content_date = new DateTime($content_date);

$now_date = new DateTime();

$since_start = $content_date->diff($now_date);

echo $since_start->days . ' days total<br>';
echo $since_start->y . ' years<br>';
echo $since_start->m . ' months<br>';
echo $since_start->d . ' days<br>';
echo $since_start->h . ' hours<br>';
echo $since_start->i . ' minutes<br>';
echo $since_start->s . ' seconds<br>';
```

Comment: Hmm this still crash my page

Comment: What format is `$row['timedate']`? The code works fine if it is in a date parseable format: https://3v4l.org/hm9Lr

Comment: Yeah i see it working on a single page

 $row['timedate'] is a datetime column type, if i echo the $row['timedate'] copy the output and put in in a single page your sample works just fine, hmm

Comment: @iiiml0sto1 that is weird! but glad it works with the rewrite.